# Wp All Export-total orders for each variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I’m using Wp All Export, and I have a problem. I want to export woocommerce orders and purchased items for each variation, but the problem is that I can’t export total orders for each variation.
For example, I have 2 separate orders for one product with the same variations like color, size, etc.
(“2x  sample Tshirt, Blue, XL” and “3x sample Tshirt, Blue, XL”)
I can’t export total ordered items quantity (in this example “5 sample Tshirt”)

Can I use a PHP function to get total ordered items? How?

*Already, I have the quantity of ordered items for each separate order in excel table.

I would really appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

you should try https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-order-export-lite/
they support "summary report by product"